# Loop array of values

Tags: php

I use the following code to get through each of values

```
foreach (array('facebook', 'twitter', 'vkontakte', 'mailru', 'odnoklassniki') as $service) {
    // Code goes here
}
```

But I feel there should be more beautiful solution than this one.

Comment: Nope, that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: It depends on what "code goes here." There are things like `array_map`  that can be useful, but there's nothing wrong with what you've got.

Comment: it would be more beautiful without vkontakte and odnoklassniki =))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imo that's the most beatiful solution

If you need further information about loops you can go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the array to a variable for readability and reuse.

```
$services = array('facebook', 'twitter', 'vkontakte', 'mailru', 'odnoklassniki');
foreach ( $services as $service) {
    // Code goes here
}
```

Depending on the situation, you could also use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($services, 'yourFunction');

function yourFunction(&$value, $key) {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have here fine as far as loops go is the right way to loop , but that does mean that you need a loop just depends on what //codes goes here is